docker-compose build takes 20 minutes because of npm install
I want to create a docker-compose for my project with SpringBoot, MongoDB and React. Everything except React builds just fine, but the React image takes literally 20 minutes to build using docker-compose because of npm install. What's weird about it is that if I try and build it by running docker build it takes 2 minutes. I'm using the same Dockerfile in both cases.
I created this project using create-react-app with utility container.
Also it's interesting that utility container used for running npm commands runs install just fine with docker-compose run --build --rm -it npm install.
Versions

Docker version 27.3.1, build ce1223035a
Docker Compose version 2.30.3

frontend (React) Dockerfile
FROM node:22

# USER node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

npm.dockerfile
FROM node:22

USER node

WORKDIR /frontend

ENTRYPOINT [ "npm" ]

docker-compose.yml
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
    env_file:
      - ./env/mongodb.env

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    env_file:
      - ./env/backend.env
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    # volumes:
    # - /app/node_modules
    # - ./frontend:/app
    env_file:
      - ./env/frontend.env

  npm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: utility/npm.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/frontend

volumes:
  mongodb:


Result from docker-compose build --no-cache frontend
The top part is way longer, filled whole scrollable terminal history.
[+] Building 1507.5s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1507.6s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1507.8s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1507.9s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1508.1s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1508.2s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1508.4s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1508.5s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1508.7s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1508.8s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1509.0s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1509.1s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1509.3s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1509.4s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1509.6s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1509.7s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1509.9s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1510.0s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1510.2s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1510.3s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1510.5s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1510.6s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1510.8s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1510.9s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1511.1s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Building 1511.1s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:22                                                                                                                    0.0s
[+] Building 1537.3s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                                                                                        docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 161B                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:22                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load build context                                                                                                                                             1.6s
 => => transferring context: 3.04MB                                                                                                                                                    1.5s
 => [frontend 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:22                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => CACHED [frontend 2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => CACHED [frontend 3/5] COPY package.json ./                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [frontend 4/5] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                  1517.7s
 => [frontend 5/5] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                           10.2s
 => [frontend] exporting to image                                                                                                                                                      7.7s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                7.7s
 => => writing image sha256:869ad09ac6bee05153fad59b4d37d474844985571993e0fa334b24c06122c1d6                                                                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/makonetv2-frontend                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [frontend] resolving provenance for metadata file

Result from docker build -t test .
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Sending build context to Docker daemon  272.8MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:22
 ---> d5175657704e
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 7d75601a1693
 ---> Removed intermediate container 7d75601a1693
 ---> 09cc0e99ea04
Step 3/7 : COPY package.json ./
 ---> 8932a31a0fc5
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in ae679d4e40af
npm warn deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm warn deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm warn deprecated workbox-google-analytics@6.6.0: It is not compatible with newer versions of GA starting with v4, as long as you are using GAv3 it should be ok, but the package is not longer being maintained
npm warn deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
npm warn deprecated q@1.5.1: You or someone you depend on is using Q, the JavaScript Promise library that gave JavaScript developers strong feelings about promises. They can almost certainly migrate to the native JavaScript promise now. Thank you literally everyone for joining me in this bet against the odds. Be excellent to each other.
npm warn deprecated
npm warn deprecated (For a CapTP with native promises, see @endo/eventual-send and @endo/captp)
npm warn deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm warn deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm warn deprecated domexception@2.0.1: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
npm warn deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.13.0: Use @eslint/config-array instead
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm warn deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm warn deprecated eslint@8.57.1: This version is no longer supported. Please see https://eslint.org/version-support for other options.

added 1458 packages, and audited 1459 packages in 2m

263 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
 ---> Removed intermediate container ae679d4e40af
 ---> 55f39b31b44d
Step 5/7 : COPY . .
 ---> 656763185240
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in 68d5d9d8dcb0
 ---> Removed intermediate container 68d5d9d8dcb0
 ---> eea07ab2f09d
Step 7/7 : CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
 ---> Running in e2055d0adb46
 ---> Removed intermediate container e2055d0adb46
 ---> 8cb35b971887
Successfully built 8cb35b971887
Successfully tagged test:latest

I tried

clearing every image, container, volume
docker builder prune
docker-compose build --no-cache frontend
with and without USER node in Dockerfile
with and without copying package-lock.json
Project created with vite and create-react-app

Honestly I have no idea why this is happening, trying to fix it for 2 days. Is there a kind soul that could help me, I'm losing my mind here

You should be good if in your Dockerfile you do this:
# Copy only the files needed for package installation first
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the files now that node_modules has been populated
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run build

Notice that:

I copy the package-lock.json to the container. This speeds up the first step of npm install: the dependency version resolution. You should add the package-lock.json file to source control (git) if you haven't already.

Copying only the package installation files allow to save the intermediate state of the image and reuse it with a modified js code: As long as no dependency change occures, the npm install step will not be re-run in the image.



I don't know what happened, I was certain I tried this already, but it works now! I wouldn't even think of checking this again. Thank you so much!
